# Issue with copy pasting of double underlined content from soreadjs to textarea

Tags: spreadjs, grapecity

While copy pasting double underlined content from soreadjs to textarea, underline not getting applied. But in the case of single underline, it is getting pasted.

When debugging it is observed that html getting from soreadjs after copying doesn't have any style for double underline. In the case of single underline content is wrapped with html tag for underline.

Please provide any solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using SpreadJS.  Double Underline is not supported in TextArea and many editors, it is custom painted in spreadjs to match Excel, however, it will not carry over in the clipboard.

This is not a limitation of the product.

Comment: How it possible if I copying multiple cells at a time and need to know in which td I have applied double underline? If I know this I can add style for double underline for that td. Please provide solution for this.

Comment: you could look at the selected cells which you copied and go through each of their styles.  https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/docs/v13/online/SpreadJS~GC.Spread.Sheets.Worksheet~getSelections.html